# Error "no such table: tablename (code 1): , while compiling: Query", code: 0

Tags: angularjs, ionic, sqlite

Estoy tratando de consultar una información que inserto en una tabla, la cual creo con anterioridad. El error es el siguiente:

```
Object {message: "no such table: HorarioP (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM HorarioP", code: 0}
```

El código donde consulto y deseo mostrar la información es el siguiente:

### horarioprof.js

**Controller**

```
mostrarHorarioProf.$inject = ['$scope', 'obtenerHorarioProf'];

function mostrarHorarioProf($scope, obtenerHorarioProf){

var Horariop;

obtenerHorarioProf.datosHorario().then(function(informacion){
   
    Horariop = informacion;
    console.log(Horariop);
    
    $scope.horario = Horariop;
    
   });

 };
```

**Service**

```
obtenerHorarioProf.$inject = ['$cordovaSQLite'];

function obtenerHorarioProf($cordovaSQLite){

return {
    
    datosHorario: function(){
        
        var sqlConsulta, db, asignatura, asignaturas, horariop, l_horario, i, fila;
        
        sqlConsulta = "SELECT * FROM HorarioP";
        asignatura = {};
        asignaturas = [];
        
        db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "unicesar.db" });
        
        horariop = $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, sqlConsulta, []).then(function(resultado) {
        
            l_horario = resultado.rows.length;
            
            for(i=0 ; i<l_horario ; i++){
                
                fila = resultado.rows.item(i);
                
                asignatura = {
                
                    codigo: fila.Codigo,
                    grupo: fila.Grupo,
                    nombre: fila.Nombre,
                    creditos: fila.Creditos,
                    dia: fila.Dia,
                    hora: fila.Hora,
                    lugar: fila.Lugar
                    
                };
                
                asignaturas.push(asignatura);
                
            }            
            
            return asignaturas;
            
        }, function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });   
        
        return horariop;            
        
    }
    
};

};
```

La tabla y la información la inserto cuando hago la petición al servidor para ingresar a la aplicacion mediante el rol de profesor o docente.

```
crearTablaHorario_P = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS HorarioP(Codigo text primary key, Grupo integer,\n\
                               Nombre text, Creditos integer, Dia text, Hora text, Lugar text,)";
        
guardarHorario_P = "INSERT INTO HorarioP(Codigo, Grupo, Nombre, Creditos, Dia, Hora, Lugar) \n\
                            VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"; 

$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, crearTablaPerfil_P);
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, crearTablaHorario_P);

for(i = 0; i < largo; i++){
            
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, guardarHorario_P, [Horario[i].CodiAsig, Horario[i].Grupo, Horario[i].NombAsig,
                                   Horario[i].Creditos, Horario[i].DiaAsig, Horario[i].HoraAsig, Horario[i].LugarAsig]);
    }
```

Gracias de antemano por cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me parece que el problema es que no pudo ejecutarse el Query para crear la Tabla, de hecho noto caracteres incorrectos `\n\` en el query:

```
crearTablaHorario_P = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS HorarioP(Codigo text primary key, Grupo integer,\n\
                               Nombre text, Creditos integer, Dia text, Hora text, Lugar text,)";
```

y al final de tu script tienes `,)";` , lo cual es también incorrecto.

Por esta razón el mensaje indica que no se encuentra dicha tabla. Trata corrigiendo el query:

```
crearTablaHorario_P = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS HorarioP(Codigo text primary key, Grupo integer, Nombre text, Creditos integer, Dia text, Hora text, Lugar text)";
```

Comment: Ok, voy a probar, aqunque, no entiendo, tengo otros querys de la misma forma, te dejo esto por aqui, pero ya mismo, hago lo que me recomiendas quizas eso puede ser, ya que la tabla para guardar el perfil si se crea de forma normal. [link](http://pastebin.com/U2REMQCx)

Comment: Entiendo Pedro, en realidad ese \n debería ser un carácter no imprimible pero no debería encontrarse dentro del Query, de hecho en sqlite te puede marcar el mensaje de token no reconocido Elimina esos caracteres de tus Queries y prueba nuevamente.

Comment: lo mismo @Elenasys, `Object {message: "no such table: HorarioP (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM HorarioP", code: 0}`

Comment: Si quieres subo el proyecto a un repositorio y te lo paso y tu lo ves cuando puedas?

Comment: Si claro con gusto Pedro, pero revisa la actualización de mi respuesta,  al final también tienes ,)"; lo cual es incorrecto.

Comment: Bueno tienes razon, al parecer era la coma esa, cuando pueda igual subo para que pruebes tu misma, gracias, creo que sera eso

Comment: Que bien Pedro!. Cuando tenemos problemas al crear tablas, regularmente son caracteres inválidos o sintaxis incorrecta,  que impiden la ejecución del query para crear la tabla.